# How can I detect the availability of cmake from a meson build config?

Tags: cmake, build, meson-build

In my meson.build there is a line

```
cmake = import('cmake')
```

which returns a CMake module object. **How can I determine whether CMake is actually available?**

I would like to do something like

```
if not cmake.found()
   # Do something without the cmake module.
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [find_program](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#find_program) function:

```
cmake_bin = find_program('cmake', required: false)
if not cmake_bin.found()
  # Do something without the cmake module.
else
  cmake = import('cmake')
  ...
endif
```